# Rails 3 redirect blocks with arity of 1 are deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 3.2.11 app I have the following routes in order to redirect www to non-www:

```
constraints(:host => /www.foo.com/) do
    root :to => redirect("http://foo.com")
    match '/*path', :to => redirect {|params| "http://foo.com/#{params[:path]}"}
end
```

Anyway rspec throws the following warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: redirect blocks with arity of 1 are deprecated. Your block must take 2 parameters: the environment, and a request object. (called from block (2 levels) in <top (required)> at /foo/config/routes.rb:6)
```

I wasn't able to find something on google so I thought to ask if anybody knows how I can get rid of this warning.

Thanks

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection shows a two var example, although, it is showing params and request not environment and request

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/Redirection/redirect also shows both

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply take a second parameter on the redirect block, thusly:

```
constraints(:host => /www.foo.com/) do
  root :to => redirect("http://foo.com")
  match '/*path', :to => redirect {|params,request| "http://foo.com/#{params[:path]}"}
end
```

You can see some documentation of this method [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Redirection.html)